# Why can't tcp use two way handshake?

Tags: tcp

Client Send `SYN` with client `isn`.
Server reply `SYN ACK` with server's `isn`.
Client resend `SYN` if timeout?

When client send data, it can accumulated confirm the server's `isn`.

I try to search, but can't find the answer.

---

I know how the tcp is designed now, I just don't know why it's designed like this. Why can't use a two way handshake.

Comment: Because that's not the way they designed it. Both sides need to know the connection is established. SCTP uses a 4-way handshake IIRC.

Comment: All messages much be acknowledged, that include the "server" `SYN` message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cannot use a two way handshake by definition.  TCP/IP is formalized as a standard for communication across networks (Internetworking).  Specifically, RFC 793 requires that:

> The "three-way handshake" is the procedure used to establish a
>     connection.  This procedure normally is initiated by one TCP and
>     responded to by another TCP.  The procedure also works if two TCP
>     simultaneously initiate the procedure.  When simultaneous attempt
>     occurs, each TCP receives a "SYN" segment which carries no
>     acknowledgment after it has sent a "SYN".  Of course, the arrival of
>     an old duplicate "SYN" segment can potentially make it appear, to the
>     recipient, that a simultaneous connection initiation is in progress.
>     Proper use of "reset" segments can disambiguate these cases.

If you think about how the protocol works, you do not actually have a single full duplex connection.  Instead, you have two simplex connections, each going in one direction.  This is why the proper response to a `SYN` is a `SYN-ACK`.  The server is *acknowledging* the synchronization request by sending the originators sequence number as the acknowledgement number plus one; it is simultaneously attempting to open its own connection to the client by sending a `SYN` request to synchronize.

The proper answer to a `SYN` will always be an `ACK`, even if the connection fails.

Regarding your question about sending a retry, yes; the client will send a retry (typically up to three, but it could be as many as eight in practice... There's no limit defined) attempting to elicit a response of some kind (preferably a SYN-ACK, but possibly a RST-ACK).

Comment: What the meaning of "full duplex connection", each side know other's isn?
In my two way design, each side also can know.

Comment: A single connection with data flowing in both directions.  TCP actually uses two half-duplex connections.